# Wix tools Ignore registry fail and continue

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to insert a registry key in wix but the result is not important
 how  can I Ignore error.

sometimes because of permission reg creation fails

```
<Component Id="EXTEND_ADVANCE_TEXT_SERVICE" Guid="*">
                      <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\SystemShared" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                        <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="CUAS" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>                            
                      </RegistryKey>
                      <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT >= 501 AND VersionNT <= 502]]></Condition>                          
                    </Component>
```

Comment: This key/value looks like it may be managed by Windows / Windows Update (TrustedInstaller). I believe you should not write anything here. What are you trying to do? What is this setting doing? Pointing a GUID at such a value and setting the component non-permanent means that your setup will rip out the value on uninstall. Perhaps intended in your case, but often it is not.

Comment: This is one of those XY questions http://xyproblem.info/  where you have a problem and believe that updating the registry is the solution, so you ask about your solution implementation instead of the original problem. Maybe you want to configure or modify a service? What exactly is the problem you're trying to address here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RegistryKey](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html) element does not have any error handling. Use a custom action and ignore the return code. There are plenty ways to do this, you can either author one in code or use a [quiet execution custom action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html).